# Is there a way to copy data from one column to another based upon data in 3rd column

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy-paste

I need to look at a worksheet that will have a variable number of rows for any value in Column X.  Where there is a value in Column X, there should be a value in Column Y.  If Column Y is blank, I need to copy the value from the same row in Column N to the blank space in Column Y. Then I need to subtract the date in Column Y from the date in Column Z to get a term in number of months.  I have struggled with the syntax for this and have not been able to even get close.  Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Test()


Dim i As Integer
 
NumRows = Range("N2", Range("N2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
 
Range("X2").Select
 
For i = 1 To NumRows
 
    If Cells(1 + X, 1) <> "" Then

        Cells(1 + n, 1).Select

                Selection.Copy
 
Range("Y").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    
    Next

End If
End Sub
```

** I expected the values in Column N to be copied to Column Y where there is a value in Column X

Answer (score 1):

```
If Cells(1 + X, 1) <> "" Then
```

1. You are referencing a variable called `X`, not a column in the workbook. As you haven't set `X` that value is just `0`, so this is essentially saying `Cells(1, 1)`, which is just `A1` in your worksheet. That's obviously not what you intended.

   - It's important to note that rows, being numeric, can be referenced by their number more-or-less directly in VBA, but columns are `alpha`. You'll have to refer to them numerically in VBA like `Cells(1, 3).Value()` would be the value stored in Cell "C1"; or, you can use `Range()` instead of `Cell`, like `Range("C1").Value()` which may feel more comfortable as you are starting out with excel automation.*
2. Furthermore when you creating your loop with `For i = 1 To NumRows`, you are assigning variable `i` to hold the numbers between `1` and `NumRows`, for each iteration of the loop, but you aren't using variable `i` in your code.
3. Also, you start an `If` block inside of your `For` loop, which is 100% above board; BUT, you end your `If` block outside of your `For` loop. That doesn't make sense. The code inside of a `For` loop runs over and over again so that `End If` must be "inside" (physically above) that `Next` line that causes the `For` to loop. Properly indenting your code will help reveal these issues when you are writing it.
4. Lastly (while this may not be causing issues, it's a code-smell), you are using `.Select` to physically select the cell upon which the code is running. Human's `.Select`, but your code doesn't need to. If you are interested in reading more about this, check out [this stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Consider instead:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NumRows as Integer

    'Changed how this is calculated. We want to start
    '  at N2 and have Excel go down to the first empty
    '  empty cell, and then grab it's row number. 
    NumRows = Range("N2").End(xlDown).Row()      


    For i = 1 To NumRows  
        
        'Using `Range()` object instead of `Cells` so 
        '  we can refer to the column letter directly  
        'Also changing the condition from `<>` to `=`
        '  since the desire is to only run the code if
        '  the value in column Y is blank.     
        If Range("Y" & i) = "" Then
            
            'copy the cell from column `N` for this 
            '  `i` row to column `Y`
            Range("N" & i).Copy        
            Range("Y" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 

            'Instead of using the clipboard to manage 
            '  copying the values around, you can just
            '  assign the value directly if you like:
            'Range("Y" & i).Value = Range("N" & i).Value

   
        
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am very new to macros and VBA but this approach makes more sense to me but when I use the recommended code, there are no resultant changes - no errors either.

Comment: Oh. I overlooked your `numrows` setting. Instead `NumRows = Range("N2").End(xlDown).Row()`. I will update the answer.

Comment: Even with the numrows adjustment I am still not seeing the data copied.  There is no change in the data.  This is the frustration I have been facing regardless of approach taken to this copy.

Comment: Rereading what you wrote in your question you say *If Column Y is blank, I need to copy the value from the same row in Column N to the blank space in Column Y.* In that case your `If` condition should change to check if it's blank. Currently it's checking if it's not blank with that `<>` condition. `If Range("Y" & i) = "" Then`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update - still no joy.  It is odd there is no error but no results either.

Comment: Progress - now I can see N3 being selected and have the "select destination and paste" message at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Nice. If the copy/paste part is giving you problems, you can switch those two lines of code over to `Range("Y" & i).Value = Range("N" & i).Value` which just directly assigns the value in Column N over to Column Y for whatever row you are iterating and avoids any funny business with Windows Clipboard.